# При добавлении нового элемента MIGX открывается пустая форма

Tags: modx, migx

При нажатии на клопку "Добавить элемент" открывается пустая форма
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Переустановка пакета не помогает, но при этом при установке выходит ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не уверен что её до этого небыло...

Консоль отображает такой косяк:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Важное замечание, изначально всё работало.

Поставил MODX на другой хостинг, повесил MIGX, не удивился конечно же, что он заработал, нашёл отличия в файлах, которые грузятся при нажатии на "Добавить элемент".
Первый вариант (поле MIGX пустое):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Больше ничего туда не грузится, тогда как в рабочем варианте выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При том файлы "connector.php" идентичны, права доступа на файлы так же идентичны и выглядят так:

```
<?php
/**
 * MIGX
 *
 * Copyright 2010 by Bruno Perner <b.perner@gmx.de>
 *
 * This file is part of MIGX.
 *
 * MIGX is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify it under the
 * terms of the GNU General Public License as published by the Free Software
 * Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or (at your option) any later
 * version.
 *
 * MIGX is distributed in the hope that it will be useful, but WITHOUT ANY
 * WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR
 * A PARTICULAR PURPOSE. See the GNU General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License along with
 * MIGX; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation, Inc., 59 Temple Place,
 * Suite 330, Boston, MA 02111-1307 USA 
 *
 * @package migx
 */
/**
 * xdbedit connector
 * 
 * @package migx
 * @subpackage controllers
 */
require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)))).'/config.core.php';
require_once MODX_CORE_PATH.'config/'.MODX_CONFIG_KEY.'.inc.php';
require_once MODX_CONNECTORS_PATH.'index.php';

$modx->lexicon->load('migx:default');

//fix for firefox - issue with iframe and form-action
$action = isset($_REQUEST['action']) ? $_REQUEST['action'] : '';
$_REQUEST['action'] = isset($_REQUEST['actionx']) ? $_REQUEST['actionx'] : $action;

/* handle request */
$miTVCorePath = $modx->getOption('migx.core_path',null,$modx->getOption('core_path').'components/migx/');
require_once $miTVCorePath.'model/migx/migx.class.php';
require_once $modx->getOption('core_path').'model/modx/modmanagercontroller.class.php';
$modx->migx = new Migx($modx);
$modx->migx->config['configs'] = isset($_REQUEST['configs']) ? $_REQUEST['configs'] : '';
$modx->migx->loadConfigs();

$modx->request->handleRequest(array(
    'processors_path' => $miTVCorePath.'processors/',
    'location' => '',
));
```

Я не очень понимаю, но что-то мне подсказывает, что в коде выше прописаны правила для вызова полей, но по какой-то причине это не происходит. Не хватает знаний что-бы понять какая из строк должна вызывать этот код, и что ему не даёт это сделать. Может быть ошибка где-то в путях или названии какого-то главного TV поля...

Comment: а что в консоли разработчика/консоли modx в site.ru/manager/?a=system/event когда 1) загружается сама страница с MIGX 2) вызывается создание MIGX. Какие версии php, modx, migx? Отключить логирование log_deprecated. Достаточно ли везде прав доступа?

Comment: Журнал ошибок пустой, была пара косяков, но не касалось MIGX (спасибо Google). Версия PHP 7.4.7, MIGX 2.12.0, MODX 2.8.1. Логирование отключил, права 755 сейчас стоят на всём сайте.

Comment: сложно сказать, напрашивается переустановка, но ведь делали, да? при переустановке были ошибки? а в логе modx при этом? ну и как вариант если возможно понизьте PHP до 7.2.

Comment: Нет, ошибки не появлялись, переустановку делал несколько раз, странная тема на самом деле

Comment: Поменял версию, поле всё так же пустое

Comment: Добавил информацию в основной вопрос, думаю там что-то есть

Comment: Вижу обсуждение еще здесь идет: https://community.modx.com/t/blank-window-when-creating-a-new-item/3366/6

Comment: Да, там как раз парень объяснил почему ошибка в коде была

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем решение оказалось до безобразия простым, в БД поменял название уже существующей таблицы для TV поля (было на русском с пробелами и ковычками) на одно слово на английском. Кто бы мог подумать, что создание новых полей сломается из за того, что у предыдущего элемента не правильное название...

Comment: а дайте больше информации пожалуйста, не ошибка ли это? Можно было бы оставить issue

Comment: Решение - ошибка? Нет, всё стало работать и работает до сих пор :)

Comment: Отлично, что разрешилось. По поводу "ошибки" - я имел ввиду, что если вариант с кириллицей и спец.символами все ломает, не нужно ли это экранировать...